# Windows terminal is unusable

Tags: windows

I just installed windows 10 pro on my laptop (I'm a windows newbie) and I have downloaded the windows terminal.
The problem is that is very slow, simple commands like `cd` takes 1-2 seconds to execute, `npm install` takes roughly 10/15 times the time it should take (my benchmark is npm on linux, installed on the same laptop).

Even copying a command from the browser to the power shell takes seconds, I can see the single letters being pasted one by one, even telnet was faster than this.

Do I have a configuration problem? Is there something I can do to speed things up?

Comment: I noticed the same thing first time I used Windows Terminal.  It worked itself out after 30-40 minutes.